# Renormalization of the Wess Zumino Witten term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, wess-zumino-witten

I was learning about the Wess-Zumino-Witten model and I encountered the the following 2-dimensional Lagrangian
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{4\lambda^2} \text{Tr}(\partial_\mu g ~\partial^{\mu} g^{-1}) + n \Gamma,$$
where $g$ is an element of $O(N)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Gamma$ the Wess-Zumino term. In the paper where I found this Lagrangian they started discussing the renormalizibility of this Lagrangian. They then state that $n$ (which has a topological origin) is not normalized as it is an integer. Then they state that the first term in the Lagrangian is renormalazible. How does one show this?

1. I tried to get the Feynman rules from a perturbative expansion. However there is no free part in the Lagrangian that one can expand around. By this I mean the Gaussian part that you normally have in the path integral. This confused me even more. How do you determine the Feynman rules? Or is it not possible to work in a perturbative expansion?
2. My initial question is: How do you show that this Lagrangian is renormalizable? How do you calculate the $\beta$-function? If you construct a perturbations series then I guess the normal counter term approach would give this, right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which of the books of the [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nonlinear_Sigma_model) article have you gone through?

Comment: This is from a paper of Witten "Non-abelian bosonization in two dimensions". Published in communications on mathematical physics.

Comment: Yes, I know. I sent you to the books first (try Ketov's) , since, if you could not reconstruct a spherical geometry, hence, one-coupling SO(N) model, you are not going to learn about infinite-coupling Friedan renormalizability from a facile answer in SE here...

Comment: In any case, after you answer most of your questions through illustrating with a metric for a hypersphere, so ***just one coupling***, the radius thereof, you might generalize through our [old pedagogical paper](https://www.academia.edu/6176942/Torsion_and_geometrostasis_in_nonlinear_sigma_models), which has an appendix on the background field technique used to renormalize theories with an infinity of couplings.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out those references. I will start there.